# Organizing and securing asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am asp.net web api newbie and basically created couple of simple web api's in asp.net. Now trying to add security and more users, and would like to do the following:

- create web api
- secure web api with oauth2
- web api would serve to agent/admins, users and guest users

What confuses me is the following

- should oauth mechanism contain information if a token is issued for admin, user or guest users
- should api contain different controllers for identical actions
  for example api/agent/orders, api/user/orders, api/guest/orders or should a single controller implement a logic in order to return data based on token information.

Not sure if the question is too broad, but would like to know how and when should tokens be properly used and how to organize web api in controllers/actions.